# Particles Breaking Through Mesh

Tags: mesh, particles

I'm using a Hair Emitter set to Volume. Is there a way to stop the particles from breaking through the mesh? [image]

Comment: Please share your .blend on pasteall.org or blendexchange

Comment: will do ..thank you

Comment: here's the file[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=bnLRwg91" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/bnLRwg91/)

Comment: maybe you shoudl create another emitter that is smaller than your current one, so that its particles don't go through your object?

Answer (score 0):

You could duplicate your object, remove the particle system of your copy, fatten it in *Edit* mode (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) so that it's thick enough that the particles don't go through (or do the opposite, i.e. shrink the original):

[image]